# Prevent dangling rvalue reference with trailing return type

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

**This function works fine:**

```
std::string get_str() {
  return std::get<0>( make_tuple(std::string("hi")) );
}
```

But if you try to do the same thing with a **trailing return type defined by `decltype`, the function returns a dangling rvalue reference**:

```
auto get_str() -> decltype( std::get<0>( make_tuple(std::string("hi")) ) ) {
  return std::get<0>( make_tuple(std::string("hi")) );
}
```

I have a cool application of trailing return type where I'd like to use `std::get`. Unfortunately, the return type of `std::get` *is* an rvalue reference in this case, so `decltype` is just doing its job...

**Do you know of a way to use the trailing return type and `decltype` but avoid the dangling rvalue reference?**

Comment: If your actual code is using tuples then consider that `typename std::tuple_element<N, tuple_type>::type` is also available to express "the type of the N-th element in a tuple".

Comment: @LucDanton +1 Thanks, I had no idea about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove the reference using the standard `remove_reference` type trait:

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

auto get_str() ->
    std::remove_reference<
        decltype( std::get<0>( make_tuple( std::string("hi") ) ) )
    >::type
{
    return std::get<0>( make_tuple( std::string("hi") ) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::remove_reference`

```
auto get_str() -> 
std::remove_reference<
    decltype( std::get<0>( make_tuple(std::string("hi")) ) )
    >::type {
  return std::get<0>( make_tuple(std::string("hi")) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds as if you want `std::remove_reference`.
So in your case simply change your trailing return type to
`std::remove_reference<decltype( std::get<0>( make_tuple(std::string("hi")) ) )>::type`